# Tcl rename of the proc keyword doesn't work well in namespaces

Tags: tcl

I have the following procedure:

```
rename proc _proc
_proc proc {name args body} {
    global pass_log_trace

    set g_log_trace "0"
    if {[info exists pass_log_trace]} {
        set g_log_trace $pass_log_trace
    }

    # simple check if we have double declaration of the same procedure
    if {[info procs $name] != ""} {
        puts "\nERROR: redeclaration of procedure: $name"
    }

    _proc $name $args $body

    if {$g_log_trace != 0} {
        trace add execution $name enter trace_report_enter
        trace add execution $name leave trace_report_leave
    }
}
```

The purpose of this procedure, mainly, is to add entry and exit point tracers to all the procedures in the code. However, for some reason it also removes the namespace scoping. For example, a code like this:

```
namespace eval bob {
    namespace eval joe {
        proc proc1 {} {}
    }
    proc proc2 {} {
        puts "proc2"
    }
}

puts "Namespace calling [info procs ::bob\::*]"
```

Would not create procedures in the `bob` namespace, but in the global namespace.
Calling `namespace current` always returns `::`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe use the tcllib logger trace command for a similar effect. http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/logger.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `_proc`, prepend the namespace of the calling context by using a combination of `uplevel` and `namespace current`:

```
set ns [uplevel 1 {namespace current}]
_proc ${ns}::$name $args $body
```

Here `uplevel 1` says, "Run this snippet of code in the caller's context", and as you already know, "namespace current" gives the fully-qualified name of the namespace it is invoked in.

Comment: If a procedure is in the highest level the $ns will be "::". Wouldn't this code create four ':' in front of $name?

Comment: Even if it did, Tcl namespaces delimiters are two or more double colons, so should do no harm.

Comment: I hate to bring this up but for some reason the code above produces error from the `Tcl_eval` call on the first call to a procedure inside a namespace. `Tcl_eval` returns error with message: `unknown command proc2`. Calling `info procs ::bob::proc2` returns correct status.

Comment: @user1476056: not sure what your expectation is -- it sounds like perhaps you are trying to call `proc2` from the global scope, but obviously you've only defined `proc2` inside of the `bob` namespace, so obviously you have to either give the fully-qualified name, `::bob::proc2`, or you must be sure to only call `proc2` when you're already in the `bob` namespace (either from another proc in the `bob` namespace, or with `namespace eval ::bob { proc2 }`.

Comment: @Eric: I understand that I would have to specify the proper namespace for `proc2`. But the error occurs before the call. It seems as if `_proc` has been run and the `Tcl_eval` returns error, before `proc2` was ever called, in any form.

Comment: @user1476056: there's clearly some additional context in your setup that you have not shared with us here -- `Tcl_eval` does not appear in your code fragment, nor anywhere in the implementation of Tcl itself. It seems likely to me that the problem you are seeing now is not related to the code you've shown, nor the modification I suggested, but rather to some other aspect of the environment in which you are testing. Without more information, it's not possible for anybody here to advise you.

Comment: @Eric: yes, it is correct, there one more component. Basically, all my code runs as a module inside a C program. The program interprets the Tcl commands using `Tcl_eval` library function.

Comment: @user1476056: Perhaps you can share the actual code you're using, if you still need help. Ideally you have a simple section of C code that demonstrates the problem you're seeing, including the call to Tcl_Eval and any setup you are doing to the interpreter.

Comment: @Eric: in order not to contaminate this question, I've created a different one with more code - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12593389/tcl-rename-of-the-proc-keyword-doesnt-work-in-namespaces-in-tcl-c-library